# How to use 'shell' output stored in a variable in further task in Ansible correctly?

Tags: shell, ansible

Lately I've been tinkering with Ansible and want to achieve following on my test node using Ansible:

- Clone a repo to the Remote Node
- `grep`  a packagelist from a textfile within the git repo
- Load the tools from the packagelist into an Ansible variable
- Install these tools via the Ansible `package` module or `apt` module.

So far I've got this:

```yaml
---
- hosts: all
  become: true
  vars:
    username: foobar

  tasks:
    - name: Install git package
      package:
        name: git
        state: present

    - name: Clone GIT Repo
      git:
        repo: https://github.com/somerepo/.dotfiles.git
        dest: /home/{{ username }}/.dotfiles
        clone: yes
        version: master
        update: yes
        force: yes

    - name: Set permission on folder ~/.dotfiles
      file:
        dest: /home/{{ username }}/.dotfiles
        recurse: yes
        owner: "{{ username }}"
        group: "{{ username }}"
        mode: "0775"

    - name: Extract list of needed tools from install.sh
      shell:
        cmd: grep "^tools=" /home/{{ username }}/.dotfiles/install.sh | tr '"' " " | cut -c7-
      register: grep_output

    - name: Install following packages "{{ grep_output }}"
      apt:
        name: "{{ grep_output }}"
        state: present
        update_cache: yes
```

The shell command gathers a list with tools:

```bash
grep "^tools=" install.sh |tr '"' " " |  cut -c7-
```

with the `STDOUT` output

```bash
zsh neovim vim tmux ranger stow wget curl git fzf
```

Those values I want to store in an Ansible variable and install it via package plugin.

When I run the playbook on my test VM

```
PLAY [all] *******************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *******************************************************************************************************
[WARNING]: Platform linux on host vm-mint21 is using the discovered Python interpreter at /usr/bin/python3.10, but future
installation of another Python interpreter could change the meaning of that path. See https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-
core/2.12/reference_appendices/interpreter_discovery.html for more information.
ok: [vm-mint21]

TASK [Install git package] ***************************************************************************************************
ok: [vm-mint21]

TASK [Clone GIT Repo] ********************************************************************************************************
changed: [vm-mint21]

TASK [Set permission on folder ~/.dotfiles] **********************************************************************************
changed: [vm-mint21]

TASK [Extract list of needed tools from install.sh] **************************************************************************
changed: [vm-mint21]

TASK [Install following packages "{'changed': True, 'stdout': ' zsh neovim vim tmux ranger stow wget curl git fzf ', 'stderr': '', 'rc': 0, 'cmd': 'grep "^tools=" /home/soeren/.dotfiles/install.sh | tr \'"\' " " | cut -c7-', 'start': '2022-09-12 22:33:37.056914', 'end': '2022-09-12 22:33:37.061264', 'delta': '0:00:00.004350', 'msg': '', 'stdout_lines': [' zsh neovim vim tmux ranger stow wget curl git fzf '], 'stderr_lines': [], 'failed': False}"] ***
fatal: [vm-mint21]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "argument 'package' is of type <class 'dict'> and we were unable to convert to list: <class 'dict'> cannot be converted to a list"}

PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************************************************************
vm-mint21                  : ok=5    changed=3    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

I get following  error:

```
argument 'package' is of type <class 'dict'> and we were unable to convert to list: <class 'dict'> cannot be converted to a list"
```

Comment: You should have inspected the content of your registered var in a debug task to see in which key the information you expect is stored (I.e. `stdout`). Moreover, your values are on one line but `apt` expects a list so you need to spilt the values on whitespace => `name: "{{ grep_output.stdout.split(' ') }}"`

Answer (score 0):

To narrow down such issue one may have a look into the following example

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Create STDOUT output
    command: 'echo "1 2 3 4 5 6"'
    register: result

  - name: Show full result
    debug:
      var: result

  - name: Show '.stdout'
    debug:
      msg: "The result in '.stdout': {{ result.stdout }} is of type {{ result.stdout | type_debug }}"
```

resulting into an output of

```
TASK [Show full result] ****************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] =>
  result:
    changed: true
    cmd:
    - echo
    - 1 2 3 4 5 6
    delta: '0:00:00.009634'
    end: '2022-09-12 23:00:00.788265'
    failed: false
    rc: 0
    start: '2022-09-12 23:00:00.778631'
    stderr: ''
    stderr_lines: []
    stdout: 1 2 3 4 5 6
    stdout_lines:
    - 1 2 3 4 5 6

TASK [Show '.stdout'] ****************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: 'The result in ''.stdout'': 1 2 3 4 5 6 is of type AnsibleUnsafeText'
```

In this way one can debug the [Return Values](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/common_return_values.html) of an Ansible module

> *Ansible modules normally return a data structure that can be registered into a variable, or seen directly when output by the `ansible` program. Each module can optionally document its own unique return values (visible through ansible-doc and on the main docsite).*

in a [variable which became registered](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#registering-variables).

> *Registered variables may be simple variables, list variables, dictionary variables, or complex nested data structures. The documentation for each module includes a `RETURN` section describing the return values for that module.*

---

For your specific case you can see that the `shell` module has a `<yourVarName>.stderr` and `<yourVarName>.stdout`, whereby you are interested in `.stdout` only. The type of the registered output is text marked as unsafe so it will not become templated.

To feed the registered output to the next module `package` or `apt`, which will require a list, you can just use the from Zeittounator within the comments mentioned `name: "{{ grep_output.stdout.split(' ') }}"` line. It will split the string into a list based on a delimiter.

Comment: Thank you for providing me with this detailed information about debugging return values. Also I thank you for fixing my initial post with formatting and spelling issues. I will improve! And I'll stop with thanks posting :)

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your last task as below. Using "split" function you can convert string to a list.

```
- name: Install following packages "{{ grep_output }}"
  apt:
    name: "{{ item }}"
    state: present
    update_cache: yes
  loop: "{{ grep_output.stdout.split() }}"
```